# is there any daemon available for bitcoin cash (eg-bitcoind for bitcoin)?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I am developing a pool for my client. i have already setup bitcoind for bitcoin but can't find daemon for bitcoin cash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bitcoin ABC](https://www.bitcoinabc.org/). But be careful because it is a fork of Bitcoin Core and uses most of the same code, including also naming its daemon `bitcoind`, so you should not install it on the same machine as Bitcoin Core.